# EF - why sometimes eager loads, sometimes lazy loads

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a common base repository method for searching (trimmed for clarity):

```
public class Repository<TRepository> : IRepository<TRepository>
        where TRepository : class, IEntity, new()
{    
     public virtual IQueryable<TRepository> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TRepository, bool>>   predicate, Expression<Func<TRepository, bool>> orderbylinq = null)
    {
        if (orderbylinq == null)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            return DbSet.Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderbylinq);
        }
    }

}
```

I have a derived repository class:

```
public class TimeDetailRepository : Repository<TimeDetail>
```

In my services layer, I have a class that calls the SearchFor method:

```
private TimeDetailRepository _timeDetailRepository;

        public ManageTimeDetailsAppServ()
            : base(new TimeDetailRepository())
        {
            _timeDetailRepository = new TimeDetailRepository();
        }
IQueryable<TimeDetail> timeDetails2 = _timeDetailRepository.SearchFor(
                    x => x.Id == 3214);
```

In this case, timeDetails2 is fully loaded (all related entities are loaded).

BUT, I have another class ( a base services layer class) that makes the same SearchFor call, yet it doesn't load the related entities:

```
IQueryable<TRepository> dbEntity = _repository.SearchFor(x => x.Id == result.Value);
```

From both calls I am trying to create a view model that utilizes property values from the related entities. Why would it load them in one case and not the other? This is the same entity TimeDetail, same base repository class?

Image of what you see in the debugger. Why would some related entities be loaded (like Facility, and TimeDetailStatus) and others not (Like OrderHeader or Customer)
[image]

**UPDATE**

I looked at the queries being generated and they both seem similar, i.e. they aren't joining to the other tables...so is it possible that the context already contains some cached rows from some of the related entities, which is how they are becoming included?

Comment: What does the question title mean?

Comment: updated, hopefully it is clearer

Comment: Maybe timeDetails2 is retrieved in chain of queries and earlier ones already retrieved entities?

Comment: Quick suggestion - you should rename `TRepository` to `TEntity`. `TRepository` makes it look like it's the type of a repository, not of an entity.

Comment: Not sure I understand. timeDetails2 is being defined for the first time there in that code. Could prior retrievals from the same table be cached or something? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JoeEnos good point. When I wrote those generic classes, I was very green...still green, but not quite as much :)

Answer (score 4):

EF will do lazy loading unless you use the `.Include()` method on the set. Since you're not doing that, you won't get them immediately, but you will get them loaded lazily when you call for them.

However, this only works if the object context is still open. If the context is gone, then your ability to connect to the database is gone, so your properties will all be null.

My guess is that the difference you're seeing has to do with how you're keeping the context around. It's hard to tell since you don't show where your context is, but I'd start there.

**EDIT**

Not sure if this will have anything to do with your issue, but I just wanted to clarify the lazy-loading stuff. Here's my favorite EF example: 2 tables: Author(AuthorId, AuthorName) and Book(BookId, AuthorId(FK), BookTitle)

```
/*  1 */ static void Main(string[] args)
/*  2 */ {
/*  3 */    Book book;
/*  4 */    using (var context = new SampleDbEntities())
/*  5 */    {
/*  6 */        book = context.Books.Single(b => b.BookId == 1);
/*  7 */    }
/*  8 */
/*  9 */    try
/* 10 */    {
/* 11 */        Console.WriteLine(book.Author.AuthorName);
/* 12 */    }
/* 13 */    catch (Exception ex)
/* 14 */    {
/* 15 */        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
/* 16 */    }
/* 17 */ 
/* 18 */    Console.ReadLine();
/* 19 */ }
```

If you run this code as-is, here's what will happen:

- Line 6 will query the `Books` table only and populate the `book` variable with the matching record. The `Authors` table is never touched in the database.
- After line 7, the context is disposed, which means data access is dead.
- Line 11 throws an exception attempting to access the `Author` property.

However, if you use the debugger and stop on line 7, just to look at the book variable for a split-second, it will immediately query the `Authors` table in the database (while you're in the debugger), and populate the `Author` property on that object. This is what I mean by lazy loading - when you actually access the property, even in the debugger, while the context is alive, it makes a new database call. You can now continue the code, and line 11 will be just fine, and the author name will be printed.

So basically, don't trust the debugger when it comes to EF. It lazy-loads data even though it doesn't look like it does. Your best bet to figure out what's going on is to fire up SQL Profiler and see what queries are run.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the input. I am new to EF so I may not be saying things correctly. What I am observing is that the result of dbEntity (from my code above) has the related entities as null when I inspect it in the debugger, right after dbEntity is set. So there is no change to the context. Not sure if this has anything to do with lazy vs eager loading...that is just what I assumed. Sorry I wasn't more clear to begin with.

Comment: @ChadRichardson See my edit regarding lazy loading. This sample shows how code behaves differently depending on when a property is accessed, and how alive the object context is.

Comment: thanks Joe for the explanation, but what I seem to have is a mix...i.e. some related entities load and others don't. See my updated question with a screen shot of what the debugger shows. Why would some load and others not?

Comment: @ChadRichardson Only thing I can think of is what you and LukLed brought up, entities already in the context. If that's it, then you must be keeping your context open for a long time - my opinion on that is that you shouldn't do that - it leads to stale data and a lot of unneeded stuff stuck in memory. I personally recommend in almost all cases to create a new context with every database call, and kill it once the call is done. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx) is a great read on the subject.

Comment: @JoeEnos with regards to `.Include()`. I was trying to access it and couldn't accept the parameters eg: `.Include(c => c.Contact)`. Is there another methods in place of that i could call? Lets say User and Contact have one-to-one.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila I don't know why they did it this way, but it only accepts a string representing the navigation property, not a lambda. So assuming your `User` has a property named `Contact`, you would do `context.Users.Include("Contact")` and the query that runs will join the `Contact` table and eagerly load that data. Someone built an extension method to allow lambdas though - [check this out](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Entity-Framework-compile-safe-Includes.aspx) - you can add it to your project and you'll be able to do it with a lambda the way you want to.

Comment: @JoeEnos I was just wondering why i could use `.Include(c => c.Contact)` in my last project and not in my current but i think i figured it out. you need to have `using System.Data.Entity;` for it to work.

Comment: I may have an idea why I am experiencing this issue. In the case where the related entities are null, I am querying the entity that I just inserted into the database. So maybe in that case it is still in the context so when I call for it, the related entities can't be looked up. Versus in the other case, I am querying and that entity isn't currently in the context so EF does a read from the database itself....? sound like that could be the difference?

Comment: Could be. I don't have a ton of experience querying things that are already in a context, since I generally open and close new contexts all the time - but I know weird things can happen when you query for something you already have. So that definitely sounds plausible.